# Create database with data

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to create my database (code first) and I want to add some data in it when it's created.

```
public class InitializerWithData : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DatabaseContext>
        {
            protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext ctx)
            {
                GroupType gt = new GroupType() { Name = "RNC" };
                //save
                ctx.GroupType.Add(gt);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public DatabaseContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new InitializerWithData());
            Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        }
```

As you can see I wrote my custom initializer but the code inside it is never fired though the database does get created.

So how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Database.CreateIfNotExists()`, it doesn't trigger the `InitializeDatabase` of the initializer. Basically it has separated implementation than the initializer.

If you want the `Seed` method to be fired. You need to execute a code that causes EF to send a query to the database.

First remove this line.

```
Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Then just execute a query, the least you could have is something like.

```
using(var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    db.Set<GroupType>().Any();
}
```

This code will create the database if it doesn't exist and execute the `Seed` method.

Comment: thanks, that was what I already tried but got "unrecognized database" or something (cant really remember). I did however fix the key length problem with MySql so maybe it had something to do with it.